# How to determine if the app pool has been terminated or suspended?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-8, quartz.net-2.0

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application that uses the Quartz.net library to execute tasks on a daily schedule. I found out pretty quickly that IIS terminates/suspends the app pool after a period of inactivity. I have changed the config for that app pool to avoid this behavior, as follows:

- Start Mode: Always Running
- Idle Time Out (minutes): 0
- Idle Time Out Action: Suspend
- Generate Recycle Log Entry: True [for all sub-properties]
- Regular Time Interval: 0
- Specific Time Interval: TimeSpan[] Array [empty]

The only possible property I could see that might still kill my app is

- Ping Enabled: True

It is set to kill any worker processes that don't respond within 90 seconds.

I am hesitant to change this property because I don't want to introduce resource leaks or anything like that.

These changes seemed to work for the past few days, but my job failed to execute again this morning.

So my question is, what can I look for in the event viewer or elsewhere that would indicate that the process/app was suspended or terminated?

I am not asking for how to improve my implementation - I am aware that a Windows Service or scheduled task, with persistent storage, would be better. I want to understand why this is happening, and where to look to find out when and why the app pool has stopped or started. I can't seem to find anything in the event viewer but perhaps I am looking in the wrong place.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be possible that there were unhanded exceptions which could crash the appPool. I think such things can be seen from Event Viewer.

Comment: Do you know what/where to look in the event viewer for AppPool information? I have logging enabled but can't find anything.

Comment: After some investigating there were some new unhandled exceptions introduced in the last commit, we've fixed those and hopefully that does it.